# How this class and sub methods use works?

Tags: php, oop, class

I have been browsing some php source code and need to know how the following class and sub methods use works:

```
<?php
$me = new Person;
$me->name("Franky")->surname("Chanyau")->phone("+22", "456 789");
?>
```

I have pretty solid knowledge of OOP so I don't want a 101. I just need to know how to make the above code possible.

Comment: *(related)* [Method Chaining](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=method+chaining+php)

Comment: This technique can also be employed to implement a Fluent Interface: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Comment: @Dennis Haarbrink - Nice. I never heard of that term before. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Method chaining is possible, by

```
return $this;
```

at the end of the method.

Explained here:
[phpandstuff: Method Chaining Plus Magic Setters](http://www.phpandstuff.com/articles/php-method-chaining-plus-magic-setters)

These methods usually set an instance variable and then just return $this.

```
public function phone($param) {
  $this->phone = $param;
  return $this;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so would it also be possible to method chain but instead of returning $this you return another object you created?

Comment: @Franky that's possible but strictly speaking Method Chaining returns the host object. Once you start to return different objects, you are going into the direction of a Fluent Interface (to create a DSL). These two are often confused.

Comment: Yes you can return another object. But from that point onwards, you can't chain methods from object 1, only methods from object 2. --edit: Not sure why you would do that, though.

Comment: Thats some deep stuff. I enjoy learning new things though. I will play around with some code and get back to you soon.

Comment: Marking it as accepted answer would really show your appreciation ;)

Comment: Am I right in assuming you can only use method chaining when "setting" properties, rather than "getting" properties? Probably a silly question but clarification would be nice.

Comment: @Ross - It doesn't matter WHAT the method does, as long as it returns the current instance ($this), you can append other methods. Of course, a normal getter function that returns the value of something, wouldnt really work, because it doesnt return $this

Answer (score 3):

methods `name()` `surname()` and `phone()` return an instance of Person. you can accomplish this by

```
return $this;
```

most probably these methods look like this:

```
public function name($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

like some others said, its a fluid interface http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#PHP the Basic Idea is that a methof of a class always returns the object itself

```
class Car {
    private $speed;
    private $color;
    private $doors;

    public function setSpeed($speed){
        $this->speed = $speed;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setColor($color) {
        $this->color = $color;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setDoors($doors) {
        $this->doors = $doors;
        return $this;
    }
}

// Fluent interface
$myCar = new Car();
$myCar->setSpeed(100)->setColor('blue')->setDoors(5);
```

(via wiki)

Comment: It's not. There is a conceptual difference between *mere* Method Chaining and a Fluent Interface. Method Chaining, by Fowler's definition, returns the Host Object. A Fluent Interface is aimed at creating a DSL. A Fluent Interface can use Method Chains (among other techniques), but a Method Chain is not a Fluent Interface. An example of a Fluent Interface would be `Zend_Db_Table`: `$table->select()->from('foo')->where('bar = baz')->assemble();`

Comment: you are right, not every time i use Method Chaining its a fluid interface but i wouldn't go so far as to say if thats what he wants to accomplish a a fluid interface or just Method Chaining ...

Answer (score 1):

It's called method chaining. Basically each class function returns the object itself (`$this`) so that the user can call more functions on the returned object.

```
public function name() {
    //other stuff...
    return $this;
}
```

http://www.talkphp.com/advanced-php-programming/1163-php5-method-chaining.html

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-method-chaining

Answer (score 0):

The idea is if we return $this then we can chain the object method calls together. Here's the solution:

```
 <?php 

    class Person
    {
        private $strName;
        private $strSurname;
        private $ArrPhone = array();

        public function name($strName)
        {
            $this->strName = $strName;
            return $this; // returns $this i.e Person 
        }

        public function surname($strSurname)
        {
            $this->strSurname = $strSurname;
            return $this; // returns $this i.e Person
        }

        public function phone() 
        {   $this->ArrPhone = func_get_args(); //get arguments as array
            return $this; // returns $this i.e Person
        }

        public function __toString()
        {
            return $this->strName." ".$this->strSurname.", ".implode(" ",$this->ArrPhone);
        }
    }

    $me = new Person;
    echo $me->name("Franky")->surname("Chanyau")->phone("+22", "456 789");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct answers, but to make the code work you should write:

```
$me = new Person();
```

instead of

```
$me = new Person;
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php - Actually.. Have a look at official php documentation, they don't use () for instantiating a new object. You would only need the brackets to send variables to the __construct() method of the class.